# Right way of browsing Instagram API result array of images with foreach

Tags: php, json, wordpress, instagram, instagram-api

I've been recently building a plugin for wordpress which basically uses the instagram API to get an image URL and then place it in a short code.

And I've come to a problem.

I get this error:

> E_WARNING : type 2 -- Invalid argument supplied for foreach() -- at
>   line 22

and I have no idea what am I doing wrong.

My code for the foreach:

```
//define Access token
$accesst= "ACCESS_TOKEN_GOES_HERE";
//userid
$userid=USERID_GOES_HERE;
//image count to get
$count=20;
//get api contents
$content = file_get_contents('https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token='.$accesst.'&count='.$count);
//converting JSON to object
$standardres = json_decode($content, true);
//array method
foreach($standardres['data'][0]['images']['standard_resolution']['url'] as $photo)
{
    print $photo['url'][0];
    echo "<br>";
}
```

My JSON `var_dump` got me this:

https://pastebin.com/3RaL6EUA

The access codes, were of course deleted before posting this.

Does anyone have a clue what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT:** 
Thanks, everyone, got it figured out in the comments.

Comment: Tried it  with `$photo[0]` instead of `$photo['url'][0]` ?

Comment: can you try this ?
foreach($standardres['data']['images'] as $image)
{
    print $image['standard_resolution']['url'];
    echo "<br>";
}

Comment: bub, yes, same result. 
Omis Brown, gives out 
"E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Undefined index: images -- at line 13

E_WARNING : type 2 -- Invalid argument supplied for foreach() -- at line 13"

adding [0] in foreach removes undefined index error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$standardres['data']` have items which have images, so you must use `$standardres['data']` in the `foreach` loop and then parse the image url from the item data.

```
foreach($standardres['data'] as $item) {
    print $item['images']['standard_resolution']['url'];
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much!! This helped!

Comment: @JacobStank you are welcome. Do not forget to mark the right answer or add your own (if no one do not provided the right answer).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly the hierarchy of the instagram API, but I suggest you to try :

```
foreach($standardres['data']['images'] as $photo) {
    print_r($photo); // to see what the array contains!
    echo $photo['standard_resolution']['url'];
    echo "<br>";
}
```